# Undefined reference to 'SDL_main' while using Dev C++

Tags: c, sdl

i am currently having problem compiling my project in dev c++ which uses SDL libraries, what i did was first download the file `SDL2-devel-2.0.3-mingw.tar.gz` (MinGW 32/64-bit) from this [site](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php), then in

Tools -> Compiler Options and then in '`Directories`' section i included the `x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib` in '`libraries`' tab and `x86_64-w64-mingw32/include` in '`C++ includes`' tab after i extracted the downloaded folder in C drive.

Finally, in project options i added these linkers

```
-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

But after compiling this code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    printf("hi\n");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT :

I tried removing const before `char*` and it said `sdl.dll` is missing so i downloaded the said file from the internet and pasted it where the project was and so the program was finally compiling but i am not getting any output as it should print "Hi"

I got the error that in Function `console_main` and undefined reference to `sdl_main`, can anyone help me rectify this problem.

Comment: Try removing `const` from `char*` main parameter.

Comment: @Zereges Please, see my latest edit above.

Comment: So do you have any compilation/linking errors or not? You wrote it compiles, but than you showed some undefined reference error. Also did you download SDL.dll from SDL page?

Comment: yes it compiles but now there's no error and it did save a file named prk.exe but when i tried to open it, nothing happened and downloaded the file from here : http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?sdl

Comment: Download the file correctly from SDL page.

Comment: can you pass on the link.

Comment: [Select correct Runtime Binaries](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php)

Comment: Still, nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is common when using int `main()` instead of :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
//or
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Try replacing it with either of these.

In the background, SDL defines a macro `#define main SDL_main` that renames your `main(int argc, char *argv[])` function so that it does not conflict with its own `main()` function (used for SDL initialization). If you use `main()` instead, the macro does not modify it and `SDL_main` is then not found.

If it does not work, follow these steps:

- When you create your project, make sure you choose a `Win32 GUI` or `Win32 Console` application type.
- After creating your project, I assume you added the following command line to your project parameters under linker : `-lmingw32 - -lSD2main -lSDL2`
- Then put `SDL2.dll` in your project directory where your executable will be.
- Include `SDL2.h` before `main(int argc, char **argv)` begins in your source code.